# Partitioning an array not coming out correctly

Tags: sorting, quicksort, partitioning

I'm trying to partition an array so that each element in the first half of the array is less than each element in the second half of the array. This is the same partition algorithm that is used in quick sort. For some reason I can get the array `A = [2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4]` to work but `A = [7, 3, 6, 1, 9, 5, 4, 8]` will not work.

```
def partition(A):
    x = A[len(A)-1]
    i = -1
    for j in range (0, len(A)-2):
        if A[j]<=x:
        i = i + 1
        # exchange A[j] and A[i]
        jValue = A[j]
        A[j] = A[i]
        A[i] = jValue
    # exchange A[len(A)-1] and A[i+1]
    rValue = A[len(A)-1]
    A[len(A)-1] = A[i+1]
    A[i+1] = rValue
    print(A)
```

Comment: To debug it 1) write what you expect to see for each pass. 2) Get the program to print out where it is and the input and output at each pass. Where don't they agree? Why? Yes, it is tedious but you will find the issue within a few minutes? ;-/ Guess how I debug code. ;-/

Comment: I did go through the whole process on paper a dozen times and the answer I get matches what my code outputs. I noticed that the reason `A = [7, 3, 6, 1, 9, 5, 4, 8]` doesn't work out the way I expect it is because the first four numbers are less than the pivot at index 7.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the code needs to pick a pivot that represents the median of the array. This could be done using quick select or something similar. Note that quick select has a worst case time complexity of O(n^2). Wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: Interesting, but it makes sense. The text I'm reading doesn't mention that at all.